# How to view google cloud VM instance RAM utilisation

Tags: charts, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, ram, utilization

I'm using Google Cloud VM instances but I can't find the RAM Utilisation chart.

When accessing through https://console.cloud.google.com, go to Hamburger Menu >> Compute Engine >> VM instances, click on one instance; there is one select box on top-left area with the following options:

- CPU utilization
- Disk bytes
- Disk operations
- Network bytes
- Network packets

But no **RAM utilization** option, where can I find this chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stackdriver monitoring for that. You can find it here: Hamburger Menu --> Stackdriver --> Monitoring. You will be directed to the Stackdriver site and the first time it will create a Stackdriver project for you.

Stackdriver is an advanced monitoring and alerting tool but the basic (free) tier includes basic metrics like memory utilization.